# I cannot show media images in templates

Tags: python, django

I cannot show media images in the templates.
I looked up similar issues on Stackoverflow but those solutions did not work for me.
I have tried adding load static at the beginning of the template. Also, I tried adding a media root with the static method in the urls.py module. Additionally, I have been attempting to use {{object.image.url}} template tag. I used all these mentioned options to view images in the template, but without the success.
Here is the code sample.

models.py

```
import os

from business.models import Business
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models


def image_upload(instance, filename):
    file_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, instance.req_object, "deals")
    if not os.path.exists(file_path):
        os.makedirs(file_path)
    return os.path.join(file_path, filename)


class Deal(models.Model):
    business = models.ForeignKey(
        to=Business, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="business_deal"
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.TextField()
    excerpt = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to=image_upload, null=True, blank=True, max_length=250
    )
    from_date = models.DateTimeField()
    to_date = models.DateTimeField()
    member_only = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    req_object = None
```

forms.py

```
from deals.models import Deal
from django import forms


class DealForm(forms.Form):
    image = forms.FileField(required=False)
    title = forms.CharField(required=True)
    description = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.Textarea)
    excerpt = forms.CharField(required=True)
    from_date = forms.DateField(required=True)
    to_date = forms.DateField(required=True)
```

urls.py from the core directory

```
from core import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.urls import include, path


def render_file(request, file_name="index.html"):
    return render(request, file_name)


urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("", include("authentication.urls", namespace="authentication")),
    path("dashboard", views.dashboard, name="dashboard"),
    path("business/", include("business.urls", namespace="business")),
    path("deals/", include("deals.urls", namespace="deals")),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

template with image

```
{% extends "business/business_base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block title %}List of Deals{% endblock %}
{% block settings_content %} 

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}         


<!--List of Deals-->
<a href="{% url 'deals:create_deal' %}" class="btn btn-primary float-right form-btn" type="submit">Add</a>
<h1 class="form-title">Deals</h1>
<br>
<p>{{number_of_items}} Result Found</p>
<br>

{% if number_of_items %}
<div class="row">
    {% for deal in deals %}
        <div class="col-4">
            <div class="card">
                {% if deal.image %}
                <img src="{{ deal.image.url }}" alt="Deal Image">
                {% else %}
                <img src="{% static 'img/grey_rectangle.webp' }" alt="Deal Image">
                {% endif %}
                <div style="background-color: #03557D;">
                    <p class="card-tag">Member to Member</p>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h3 class="card-title">{{ deal.title }}</h3>
                  <p class="card-text">{{ deal.description }}</p>
                  <br>
                  <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Valid: {{deal.from_date|date:"m/d/Y"}} - {{deal.to_date|date:"m/d/Y"}}</small></p>
                </div>
              </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

views.py

```
from authentication.models import BusinessOwner
from deals.forms import DealForm
from deals.models import Deal
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from django.urls import reverse


@login_required
def create_deal(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = DealForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            business_owner = BusinessOwner.objects.get(user=request.user)
            deal = Deal(
                title=form.cleaned_data["title"],
                description=form.cleaned_data["description"],
                excerpt=form.cleaned_data["excerpt"],
                from_date=form.cleaned_data["from_date"],
                to_date=form.cleaned_data["to_date"],
                image=form.cleaned_data["image"],
            )
            deal.req_object = request.user.email
            deal.business = business_owner.business
            deal.save()
            return redirect(reverse("deals:deals_list"))
    form = DealForm()
    return render(
        request=request,
        template_name="deals/create_deal.html",
        context={"form": form},
    )


@login_required
def list_of_deals_from_setting(request):
    business_owner = BusinessOwner.objects.get(user=request.user)
    deals = Deal.objects.filter(business_id=business_owner.business.id)
    context = {"deals": list(deals.values()), "number_of_items": deals.values().count()}
    return render(request, "deals/deals_list.html", context=context)
```

settings.py

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

from django.contrib.messages import constants as messages
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

SECRET_KEY = os.getenv("SECRET_KEY", "")

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "rest_framework",
    "corsheaders",
    "rest_framework.authtoken",
    "crispy_forms",
    "profiles",
    "authentication",
    "business",
    "deals",
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
]

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = "bootstrap4"

ROOT_URLCONF = "core.urls"

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "build"),
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates"),
        ],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
            ],
        },
    },
]

MESSAGE_TAGS = {
    messages.DEBUG: "alert-secondary",
    messages.INFO: "alert-info",
    messages.SUCCESS: "alert-success",
    messages.WARNING: "alert-warning",
    messages.ERROR: "alert-danger",
}

WSGI_APPLICATION = "core.wsgi.application"


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#databases
if DEBUG:
    DATABASES = {
        "default": {
            "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.sqlite3",
            "NAME": BASE_DIR / "db.sqlite3",
        }
    }
else:
    DATABASES = {
        "default": {
            "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.mysql",
            "NAME": os.getenv("DB_NAME", ""),
            "USER": os.getenv("DB_USER", ""),
            "PASSWORD": os.getenv("DB_PASSWORD", ""),
            "HOST": os.getenv("DB_HOST", ""),
            "PORT": os.getenv("DB_PORT", ""),
        }
    }


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator",
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = "en-us"

TIME_ZONE = "UTC"

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = "static/"
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "build/static"),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]

STATICFILES_STORAGE = "whitenoise.storage.CompressedStaticFilesStorage"
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles")

WHITENOISE_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "build")

# Media files
MEDIA_ROOT = MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = "django.db.models.BigAutoField"

CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True

AUTH_USER_MODEL = "profiles.User"

# REST Framework Settings
# https://www.django-rest-framework.org/

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": [
        "rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication",
    ],
    "DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES": [
        "rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer",
    ],
    "DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES": [
        "rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser",
    ],
}
```

Comment: When you try to open image url manually, what's the error message in django error log and http status in browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call list() on a queryset in Django, it creates a Python list object containing the same data as the queryset. However, the queryset itself is still lazily evaluated - that is, the database query has not yet been executed.

This means that if you use list() to convert a queryset containing ImageField objects to a Python list in your view, the ImageField instances in the queryset will not be resolved to their corresponding URLs. This is because the URLs are only generated when the queryset is evaluated, which doesn't happen until later.

To ensure that the ImageField instances are resolved to their corresponding URLs, you need to avoid using list() and instead pass the queryset directly to the template context. This way, the queryset will be evaluated when it is accessed in the template, allowing the ImageField instances to be resolved to their corresponding URLs.

Try the following in your views.py:

```
@login_required
def list_of_deals_from_setting(request):
    business_owner = BusinessOwner.objects.get(user=request.user)
    deals = Deal.objects.filter(business_id=business_owner.business.id)
    context = {"deals": deals, "number_of_items": deals.values().count()}
    return render(request, "deals/deals_list.html", context=context)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I changed it as you suggested, and it is working now.

Answer (score 1):

in your template, image source misses a %

it's: 
"{% static 'img/grey_rectangle.webp' }"

should be: 
"{% static 'img/grey_rectangle.webp' %}"

in case that doesn't work either try changing image src to:  
src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}img/grey_rectangle.webp"

Comment: Thank you. I missed that error, and the image is showing up now.